# VB.net How to convert image file to pdf file and then save it without using SaveFileDialog?

Tags: vb.net

I already manage to convert the image file to pdf file.. but i want to make it automatically save to specific location and without it asking me where to save it. Please help me, any help would be appreciated. Beginner here. Here is the code that im currently trying.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf
Imports PdfSharp.Drawing
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub captureScreen()

        'Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim graph As Graphics = Nothing

        Try

            ' gets the upper left hand coordinate of the form
            Dim frmleft As System.Drawing.Point = Me.Bounds.Location

            'use the commented out version for the full screen
            'Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)

            'this version get the size of the form1  The + 8 adds a little to right and bottom of what is captured.
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Bounds.Width + 8, Me.Bounds.Height + 8)

            'creates the grapgic
            graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

            'Gets the x,y coordinates from the upper left start point
            'used below  
            Dim screenx As Integer = frmleft.X
            Dim screeny As Integer = frmleft.Y

            ' The - 5 here allows more of the form to be shown for the top and left sides.
            graph.CopyFromScreen(screenx - 5, screeny - 5, 0, 0, bmp.Size)

            ' Save the Screenshot to a file
            bmp.Save("I:\eQA\temp.png")

            bmp.Dispose()
            graph.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        captureScreen()

        ' Create new pdf document and page
        Dim doc As New PdfDocument()
        Dim oPage As New PdfPage()


        ' Add the page to the pdf document and add the captured image to it
        doc.Pages.Add(oPage)
        'Dim xgr As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage)
        Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromFile("I:\eQA\temp.png")
        'xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0)

        'Create XImage object from file.
        Using xImg = PdfSharp.Drawing.XImage.FromFile("I:\eQA\temp.png")
            'Resize page Width and Height to fit image size.
            oPage.Width = xImg.PixelWidth * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution
            oPage.Height = xImg.PixelHeight * 72 / xImg.HorizontalResolution

            'Draw current image file to page.
            Dim xgr = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage)
            xgr.DrawImage(xImg, 0, 0, oPage.Width, oPage.Height)

        End Using

        ' instantiate a Bitmap object
        Dim filesaveas As New SaveFileDialog
        filesaveas.Filter = ("PDF File|*.pdf")


        Dim btnSave As DialogResult = filesaveas.ShowDialog()
        If btnSave.Equals(DialogResult.OK) Then
            doc.Save(filesaveas.FileName)
            doc.Close()
        End If

        ' I used the Dispose() function to be able to 
        ' save the same form again, in case some values have changed.
        ' When I didn't use the function, an GDI+ error occurred.
        img.Dispose()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you don't want the `SaveFileDialog`, then don't show it.  Just remove those lines and call `doc.Save` with a `string` variable that contains the location where you want the file saved.  I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: my issue is i dont want to use SaveFileDialog, i just want it to directly save the PDF to some directory without any showdialog comes out and ask me to save the file.

Comment: You are creating the SaveFileDialog yourself with this line:  `Dim filesaveas As New SaveFileDialog` and then you are showing it with this line:  `Dim btnSave As DialogResult = filesaveas.ShowDialog()`.  If you don't want that, then delete those lines.

Comment: Okay thanks.. i know that, but its okay i finally figured out how to do it. Thanks for great suggestion. ^^